# Switching where my domain points to for safe production deploys

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, production-environment, dev-to-production

Say I have one prod environment and one dev environment in elastic beanstalk. I deploy my code to dev and it works and all's well, but when I deploy to production I get an error (note this is possible since sometimes instances get corrupted during deploys and apache breaks). What are the pros and cons of this solution:

1. have 2 prod environments that you toggle between on every deploy
2. deploy to the one not being used
3. if the deploy works, point yourdomain.com to the new production and if not, your old production is safe

Now, is SEO a concern -- if I switch around my domain between two elastic beanstalk environments, would the SEO be harmed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution is one that I have used many times without incident but remember to always test you solutions before production use.

The solution will use the following environment names which you should map to internal DNS names:

**PROD01**.elasticbeanstalk.com > www.example.com
**PROD02**.elasticbeanstalk.com
**DEV01**.elasticbeanstalk.com > dev-www.example.com

Typically, after developing and testing your application locally, you will deploy your application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment **DEV01**. At this point, your application will be live at URL dev-www.example.com.

Now that you have tested your application, it is easy to edit your application, redeploy, and see the results.

When you are satisfied your changes you made to your application, you can deploy it to your **PROD02**.elasticbeanstalk.com production environment. Using the *Application Versions page* promote the code running on **DEV01** onto **PROD02**. Using your hosts file make sure everything is in order and then hit the *URL swap.*

This will switch **PROD01**.elasticbeanstalk.com and **PROD02**.elasticbeanstalk.com environment URL's seamlessly with zero downtime on your application.

Once you've made sure all your traffic is switched you can then update your original production environment following the same method, switch back and remove **PROD01**.elasticbeanstalk.com to prevent the extra cost (or you can leave it if you don't mind the $$ spend).

Comment: overall, makes sense. after you promote dev01 to prod02, prod02 has the new version of the site. after the switch, doesn't prod01 have the new version of the site? so, wouldn't we want to remove prod02? forgive me if i am misunderstanding what you are saying.

Comment: after the switch prod01 has the old version of the site. When you've switched and everything is awesome, you can update prod01 (using the EB console), switch back and finally removing prod02.

Comment: but this trick will change ip address resolved underneath after each switch. This can potentially harm seo, cannot it?

Comment: How so? SEO is against a domain; not a IP address.